# Xarray or Multi Index DataFrame for large scale data analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I just found out how to import loads of historical stock prices into an array at http://www.pythonforfinance.net/2017/01/21/investment-portfolio-optimisation-with-python/

I did this using this code

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

#yf.pdr_override()

source = 'yahoo'
stocks = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'GE']
start = '2017-01-01'
end_date = '2017-12-10'

data_array = pdr.DataReader(stocks, source, start,)['Adj Close']

print (data_array)
```

The issue is that I have a warning

> Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. The
>   recommended way to represent these types of 3-dimensional data are
>   with a MultiIndex on a DataFrame, via the Panel.to_frame() method
>   Alternatively, you can use the xarray package
>   http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/. Pandas provides a `.to_xarray()`
>   method to help automate this conversion.

So I need advice, my goal is to save the data to CSV or excel file.  Second step will be to take the average of the last x days of prices and divide the current price by the average and finally then to do a percent rank on the stocks for each day.  Given the multiple steps, I figured to write it all to excel one step after another and to save myself from having to recalculate all history each day.

**QUESTION:**  Given this ambition, what would be better method:  Xarray or MultiIndex on DataFrame?

Comment: This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876278/when-to-use-multiindexing-vs-xarray-in-pandas

Comment: Have you figured out an answer to your question? It would help me, if you could answer your own question :)