# Convert a multiway pandas.crosstab to an xarray

Tags: pandas, python-xarray, tabulate

I want to create a multiway contingency table from my pandas dataframe and store it in an xarray. It seems to me it ought to be straightfoward enough using [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) followed by [DataFrame.to_xarray()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html) but I'm getting  "TypeError: Cannot interpret 'interval[int64]' as a data type" in pandas v1.1.5. (v1.0.1 gives "ValueError: all arrays must be same length").

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: pd.__version__
Out[1]: '1.1.5'

In [2]: import xarray as xr
   ...: xr.__version__
Out[2]: '0.17.0'

In [3]: n = 100
   ...: np.random.seed(42)
   ...: x = pd.cut(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=3, size=n), range(5))
   ...: x
Out[3]: 
[(1, 2], (2, 3], (2, 3], (1, 2], (0, 1], ..., (1, 2], (1, 2], (1, 2], (0, 1], (0, 1]]
Length: 100
Categories (4, interval[int64]): [(0, 1] < (1, 2] < (2, 3] < (3, 4]]

In [4]: x.value_counts().sort_index()
Out[4]: 
(0, 1]    41
(1, 2]    28
(2, 3]    31
(3, 4]     0
dtype: int64
```

Note I need my table to include empty categories such as (3, 4].

```
In [6]: idx=pd.date_range('2001-01-01', periods=n, freq='8H')
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x}, index=idx)
   ...: df['xlag'] = df.x.shift(1, 'D')
   ...: df['h'] = df.index.hour
   ...: xtab = pd.crosstab([df.h, df.xlag], df.x, dropna=False, normalize='index')
   ...: xtab
Out[6]: 
x            (0, 1]    (1, 2]    (2, 3]  (3, 4]
h  xlag                                        
0  (0, 1]  0.000000  0.700000  0.300000     0.0
   (1, 2]  0.470588  0.411765  0.117647     0.0
   (2, 3]  0.500000  0.333333  0.166667     0.0
   (3, 4]  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000     0.0
8  (0, 1]  0.588235  0.000000  0.411765     0.0
   (1, 2]  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000     0.0
   (2, 3]  0.428571  0.142857  0.428571     0.0
   (3, 4]  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000     0.0
16 (0, 1]  0.333333  0.250000  0.416667     0.0
   (1, 2]  0.444444  0.222222  0.333333     0.0
   (2, 3]  0.454545  0.363636  0.181818     0.0
   (3, 4]  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000     0.0
```

That's fine, but my actual application has more categories and more dimensions, so this seems a clear use-case for xarray, but I get an error:

```
In [8]: xtab.to_xarray()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-aaedf730bb97> in <module>
----> 1 xtab.to_xarray()

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_xarray(self)
   2818             return xarray.DataArray.from_series(self)
   2819         else:
-> 2820             return xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe(self)
   2821 
   2822     @Substitution(returns=fmt.return_docstring)

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in from_dataframe(cls, dataframe, sparse)
   5131             obj._set_sparse_data_from_dataframe(idx, arrays, dims)
   5132         else:
-> 5133             obj._set_numpy_data_from_dataframe(idx, arrays, dims)
   5134         return obj
   5135 

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in _set_numpy_data_from_dataframe(self, idx, arrays, dims)
   5062                 data = np.zeros(shape, values.dtype)
   5063             data[indexer] = values
-> 5064             self[name] = (dims, data)
   5065 
   5066     @classmethod

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   1427             )
   1428 
-> 1429         self.update({key: value})
   1430 
   1431     def __delitem__(self, key: Hashable) -> None:

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in update(self, other)
   3897         Dataset.assign
   3898         """
-> 3899         merge_result = dataset_update_method(self, other)
   3900         return self._replace(inplace=True, **merge_result._asdict())
   3901 

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py in dataset_update_method(dataset, other)
    958         priority_arg=1,
    959         indexes=indexes,
--> 960         combine_attrs="override",
    961     )

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py in merge_core(objects, compat, join, combine_attrs, priority_arg, explicit_coords, indexes, fill_value)
    609     coerced = coerce_pandas_values(objects)
    610     aligned = deep_align(
--> 611         coerced, join=join, copy=False, indexes=indexes, fill_value=fill_value
    612     )
    613     collected = collect_variables_and_indexes(aligned)

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py in deep_align(objects, join, copy, indexes, exclude, raise_on_invalid, fill_value)
    428         indexes=indexes,
    429         exclude=exclude,
--> 430         fill_value=fill_value,
    431     )
    432 

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py in align(join, copy, indexes, exclude, fill_value, *objects)
    352         if not valid_indexers:
    353             # fast path for no reindexing necessary
--> 354             new_obj = obj.copy(deep=copy)
    355         else:
    356             new_obj = obj.reindex(

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in copy(self, deep, data)
   1218         """
   1219         if data is None:
-> 1220             variables = {k: v.copy(deep=deep) for k, v in self._variables.items()}
   1221         elif not utils.is_dict_like(data):
   1222             raise ValueError("Data must be dict-like")

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
   1218         """
   1219         if data is None:
-> 1220             variables = {k: v.copy(deep=deep) for k, v in self._variables.items()}
   1221         elif not utils.is_dict_like(data):
   1222             raise ValueError("Data must be dict-like")

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py in copy(self, deep, data)
   2632         """
   2633         if data is None:
-> 2634             data = self._data.copy(deep=deep)
   2635         else:
   2636             data = as_compatible_data(data)

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in copy(self, deep)
   1484         # 8000341
   1485         array = self.array.copy(deep=True) if deep else self.array
-> 1486         return PandasIndexAdapter(array, self._dtype)

/opt/scitools/environments/default/2021_03_18-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in __init__(self, array, dtype)
   1407                 dtype_ = array.dtype
   1408         else:
-> 1409             dtype_ = np.dtype(dtype)
   1410         self._dtype = dtype_
   1411 

TypeError: Cannot interpret 'interval[int64]' as a data type
```

I can avoid the error by converting x (and xlag) to a different dtype instead of pandas.Categorical before using pandas.crosstab, but then I lose any empty categories, which I need to keep in my real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the use of a `CategoricalIndex` but the category labels (x.categories) is an `IntervalIndex` which `xarray` doesn't like.

To remedy this, you can simply replace the categories within your `x` variable with their string representation, which coerces `x.categories` to be an "object" dtype instead of an "interval[int64]" dtype:

```
x = (
    pd.cut(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=3, size=n), range(5))
    .rename_categories(str)
)
```

Then calculate your crosstab as you have already done and it should work!

---

To get your dataset in the coordinates you want (I think), all you need to do is to stack everything in a single `MultiIndex` row shape. (instead of a crosstab `MultiIndex` row/`Index` column shape).

```
xtab = (
    pd.crosstab([df.h, df.xlag], df.x, dropna=False, normalize="index")
    .stack()
    .reorder_levels(["x", "h", "xlag"])
    .sort_index()
)
xtab.to_xarray()
```

If you want to shorten your code and lose some of the explicit ordering of index levels, you can also use `unstack` instead of stack which gives you the correct ordering right away:

```
xtab = (
    pd.crosstab([df.h, df.xlag], df.x, dropna=False, normalize="index")
    .unstack([0, 1])
)
xtab.to_xarray()
```

Regardless of the `stack()` vs `unstack([0, 1])` approach you use, you get this output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4, h: 3, xlag: 4)>
array([[[0.        , 0.47058824, 0.5       , 0.        ],
        [0.58823529, 1.        , 0.42857143, 0.        ],
        [0.33333333, 0.44444444, 0.45454545, 0.        ]],

       [[0.7       , 0.41176471, 0.33333333, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.14285714, 0.        ],
        [0.25      , 0.22222222, 0.36363636, 0.        ]],

       [[0.3       , 0.11764706, 0.16666667, 0.        ],
        [0.41176471, 0.        , 0.42857143, 0.        ],
        [0.41666667, 0.33333333, 0.18181818, 0.        ]],

       [[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) object '(0, 1]' '(1, 2]' '(2, 3]' '(3, 4]'
  * h        (h) int64 0 8 16
  * xlag     (xlag) object '(0, 1]' '(1, 2]' '(2, 3]' '(3, 4]'
```

Comment: Many thanks! That's the key to my problem, though there are a couple of extra reshaping things (see answer I'll post in a minute). 

Even if I'd found [CategoricalIndex.rename_categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.rename_categories.html), I would never have worked out that I could use `str` as a 'callable' parameter to achieve what I want. 

I can't find an IntervalIndex.rename_categories  - I guess IntervalIndex inherits the method from CategoricalIndex?? If so I don't understand how I'm meant to know that from its documentation page...

Comment: So a `CategoricalIndex` (or any category array) are composed of 2 arrays. `values` which are always an integer dtype under the hood are the exposed values that you see in the array. Each number maps to a label into the second array within a Categorical: the `categories`. The `categories` is an array all on its own with its own dtype. In this case the `categories` were an `IntervalIndex` all we did was replace it with an array with "object" dtype (which `xarray` can understand).

Comment: Thanks for adding to your answer in response to mine below. Per my answer below I actually wanted the coordinates in the order ('h', 'xlag', 'x'), which it turns out I can obtain simply using stack alone, i.e.:
pd.crosstab([df.h, df.xlag], df.x, dropna=False, normalize="index").stack().to_xarray()

Comment: perfect, sorry for the misunderstanding on the order of the dimensions. But glad you were able to piece it together!

Comment: No worries! Not sure if you want to edit your answer again in light of my previous comment? It would simplify it for future reference (tbh i don't understand the unstack method anyway)

Answer (score 0):

@Cameron-Riddell's answer is the key to my problem, but there are a couple of additional reshaping wriggles to smooth out. Applying `rename_categories(str)` to my `x` variable as he suggests then proceeding as in my question allows the final line to work:

```
In [8]: xtab = pd.crosstab([df.h, df.xlag], df.x, dropna=False, normalize='index')
   ...: xtab.to_xarray()
Out[8]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (h: 3, xlag: 4)
Coordinates:
  * h        (h) int64 0 8 16
  * xlag     (xlag) object '(0, 1]' '(1, 2]' '(2, 3]' '(3, 4]'
Data variables:
    (0, 1]   (h, xlag) float64 0.0 0.4706 0.5 0.0 ... 0.3333 0.4444 0.4545 0.0
    (1, 2]   (h, xlag) float64 0.7 0.4118 0.3333 0.0 ... 0.25 0.2222 0.3636 0.0
    (2, 3]   (h, xlag) float64 0.3 0.1176 0.1667 0.0 ... 0.3333 0.1818 0.0
    (3, 4]   (h, xlag) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

But I wanted a 3-d array with one variable, not a 2-d array with 3 variables. To convert it I need to apply `.to_array(dim='x')`. But then my dimensions are in the order `x`, `h`, `xlag` and I clearly don't want `h` in the middle so I also need to transpose them:

```
In [9]: xtab.to_xarray().to_array(dim='x').transpose('h', 'xlag', 'x')
Out[9]: 
<xarray.DataArray (h: 3, xlag: 4, x: 4)>
array([[[0.        , 0.7       , 0.3       , 0.        ],
        [0.47058824, 0.41176471, 0.11764706, 0.        ],
        [0.5       , 0.33333333, 0.16666667, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.58823529, 0.        , 0.41176471, 0.        ],
        [1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.42857143, 0.14285714, 0.42857143, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.33333333, 0.25      , 0.41666667, 0.        ],
        [0.44444444, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.        ],
        [0.45454545, 0.36363636, 0.18181818, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]])
Coordinates:
  * h        (h) int64 0 8 16
  * xlag     (xlag) object '(0, 1]' '(1, 2]' '(2, 3]' '(3, 4]'
  * x        (x) <U6 '(0, 1]' '(1, 2]' '(2, 3]' '(3, 4]'
```

*That's* what I'd envisaged! It displays similarly to pd.crosstab, but it's a 3-d xarray instead of a pandas dataframe with a multiindex. That'll be much easier to handle in the subsequent stages of my program (the crosstab is just an intermediate step, not a result in itself).

I must say that ended up more complicated than I'd anticipated... I found a question from @kilojoules back in 2017 "[When to use multiindexing vs. xarray in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42876278/492043)" to which [@Tkanno wrote an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172361/492043) beginning "There does seem to be a transition to xarray for doing work on multi-dimensional arrays." Seems a shame to me that there isn't a version of pd.crosstab that returns an xarray - or am I asking for more pandas-xarray integration than is possible?

Comment: Typically we ask you to create a new questions when adding in a part 2 to an existing question. But I'm already here, so I'll go ahead and respond to your answer. I'm not super familiar with `xarray` but I think I do have a solution to what you posted here. I'll edit it into my original post.

Comment: That's most kind of you Cameron, many thanks, your solution is much simpler and more elegant than mine above and has greatly clarified my understanding of pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray. I've accepted your answer.